# Color change in Pattern Brushes

Tags: adobe-illustrator

- I'm experiencing a problem with image pattern brushes that I use to decorate certain complex surfaces:
- I'm creating it from a psd grayscale with 4 Pantones file.
- When I apply it to a straight line it's fine but if I apply it to a circle, a washed lighter color appears instead as you can see in the image below...

Does anyone have a solution to avoid this problem ?

[image]

Comment: It seems u changed colorization method in pattern brush settings. try to change it to `none`

Comment: Thank you so much Danielito. I over checked that.

Comment: I am attaching the ai file so You can see in the file itself...

Comment: not working have to link it here probably